# hiding tableview index dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

in the iphone sdk, is there any way to dynamically decide whether or not to show the index at the side of a table view, and the sections as well?  For example, I would like to show the index "A...Z" if the table has over 50 entries, but I would like to hide it if it's less than that.  Can that be decided dynamically?  I am using UILocalizedIndexedCollation to display the index.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableView has a property called `sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount` - the number of table rows at which to display the index list on the right edge of the table.

Comment: thanks!  I think this is what I'm looking for.  On a related note, how do you dynamically decide whether to show sections in the table view?  For example, if I only have one entry, I don't want to show all 26 letters of the alphabet for the sections.  I just want either show one section or no sections at all.

Answer (score 0):

Code as follows,

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

if([datasource count]<50)
return nil;

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempArray addObject:@"1"];
[tempArray addObject:@"2"];
[tempArray addObject:@"3"];
[tempArray addObject:@"4"];
[tempArray addObject:@"5"];
[tempArray addObject:@"6"];
[tempArray addObject:@"7"];
[tempArray addObject:@"8"];
[tempArray addObject:@"9"];
[tempArray addObject:@"10"];
[tempArray addObject:@"11"];
[tempArray addObject:@"12"];
[tempArray addObject:@"13"];
[tempArray addObject:@"14"];
[tempArray addObject:@"15"];
[tempArray addObject:@"16"];
[tempArray addObject:@"17"];
[tempArray addObject:@"18"];
[tempArray addObject:@"19"];
[tempArray addObject:@"20"];
[tempArray addObject:@"21"];
[tempArray addObject:@"22"];
[tempArray addObject:@"23"];
[tempArray addObject:@"24"];
[tempArray addObject:@"25"];
[tempArray addObject:@"26"];

return tempArray;
}
```